# reading a file and reverse it to another file?

Tags: c

i have this code but every time i try to run it it deletes the source file without giving any output, so how can i fix my problem?

note the question is asking me this:

*Write a program that takes two ﬁle names from the command line, and copies the reverse of the contents of the ﬁrst ﬁle into the second ﬁle, assuming that it is able to open the ﬁrst ﬁle for reading and the second one for writing. If it can’t open the ﬁrst ﬁle for reading, it must neither create nor modify (as the case may be) the second ﬁle. This program must use the low-level functions*

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h> 
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int source, dest, n;
    char buf;
    int filesize;
    int i;


    if (argc != 3)
    {   
    fprintf(stderr, "usage %s <source> <dest>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }
```

at this par i am trying to use the following format: open("outf", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666)

```
   if ((source = open(argv[1],O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666)) < 0)
   { //read permission for user on source 

       fprintf(stderr, "can't open source\n");
       exit(-1);
   }


   if ((dest = creat(argv[2], 0666)) < 0)
   { //rwx permission for user on dest

       fprintf(stderr, "can't create dest");

       exit(-1);
   }

   filesize = lseek(source, (off_t) 0, SEEK_END); //filesize is lastby +offset

   printf("Source file size is %d\n", filesize);


   for (i = filesize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   { //read byte by byte from end

       lseek(source, (off_t) i, SEEK_SET);


       n = read(source, &buf, 1);


       if (n != 1)
       {

       fprintf(stderr, "can't read 1 byte\n");
       exit(-1);
       }

       n = write(dest, &buf, 1);

       if (n != 1)
       {
       fprintf(stderr, "can't write 1 byte\n");

       exit(-1);
       }


   }

   write(STDOUT_FILENO, "DONE\n", 5);

   close(source);

   close(dest);

   return 0;
}
```

thanks

Comment: Is this a C or C++ question? Sounds and looks more like a C question than anything else.

Comment: Your opening your source `argv[1]` according to your help line with `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`... So telling the system that the file handler is "write only/create file if it does not exist/truncate file if it exists"

Answer (score 4):

I am sorry to be rude but did you even read the options you are passing to the first open call? `O_CREAT | O_TRUNC`?

What do you think those options do? Those options are causing your source file to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your ***input*** file with the mode `O_RDONLY`, i.e. **ReaD ONLY** *not* `O_WRONLY`, i.e. **WRite ONLY**.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
int checkstatus(ifstream &in)
{
ios::iostate i;
i = in.rdstate();
if(i & ios::eofbit)
return 0;//cout << "EOF encountered\n";
else if(i & ios::failbit)
return 0;//cout<<"Non-Fatal I/O error\n";
else if(i & ios::badbit)
return 0;//cout<<"Fatal I/O error\n";

return 1;
}


int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    ofstream o;
    in.open("test.txt");
    o.open("test1.txt",ios::out);
    char c;
    in.seekg(0,ios::end);
        while(checkstatus(in) != 0)
        {
            in.seekg(-1,ios::cur);
            in.get(c);
            in.seekg(-1,ios::cur);
            if(checkstatus(in) == 0)
            break;
            cout<<c;
            o.put(c);

        }
        in.close();
        o.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have made some changes here and it worked very decent but not with very large file!!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/stat.h> 
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int source, dest, n;
    char buf;
    int filesize;
    int i;


    if (argc != 3)
    {   
    fprintf(stderr, "usage %s <source> <dest>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

   if ((source = open(argv[1], 0666)) < 0)
   { //read permission for user on source

       fprintf(stderr, "can't open source\n");
       exit(-1);
   }


   if ((dest = open(argv[2],O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666)) < 0)
   { //rwx permission for user on dest

       fprintf(stderr, "can't create dest");

       exit(-1);
   }

   filesize = lseek(source, (off_t) 0, SEEK_END); //filesize is lastby +offset

   printf("Source file size is %d\n", filesize);


   for (i = filesize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   { //read byte by byte from end

       lseek(source, (off_t) i, SEEK_SET);


       n = read(source, &buf, 1);


       if (n != 1)
       {

       fprintf(stderr, "can't read 1 byte\n");
       exit(-1);
       }

       n = write(dest, &buf, 1);

       if (n != 1)
       {
       fprintf(stderr, "can't write 1 byte\n");

       exit(-1);
       }


   }

   write(STDOUT_FILENO, "DONE\n", 5);

   close(source);

   close(dest);

   return 0;
}
```

do i need to do something with lseek()?